# copies of classes in python

Tags: python

Assume I have an instance foo of some class Class with some variable foo.x. Now I want to produce a copy of foo:

```
bar = foo
```

when I now change bar.x, this also changes foo.x. How can I get a copy of foo, where I can change everything without changing the original foo? Creating a new instance of Class is not an option, because I need it in the state in which foo already is.

Comment: You need a new instance for sure, because a copy is a new instance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the module copy.

```
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html):

```
bar = deepcopy(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also implement your own copy with customized(sure if you really need this) behavior the following way:

```
from copy import copy

class d(object):

    def __copy__(self):
        newd = d()
        newd.x = self.x+1
        return newd

foo = d()
foo.x = 11
a = copy(d)
print a.x, foo.x
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but that looks very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @Till B - you are welcome, i have posted it so you can have one more option to do what you want, so you are able to customize copying any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

bar = copy.copy(foo)         # make a shallow copy of foo

bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)     # make a deep copy of foo

copy(x)
    Shallow copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.

deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[])
    Deep copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.